# Friendship Website Database Design

Tags: sql-server, database, normalization

I'm trying to create a database for a frienship website I'm building. I want to store multiple attributes about the user such as gender, education, pets etc.

Solution #1 - `User` table:

```
id | age | birth day | City     | Gender | Education  | fav Pet | fav hobbie. . .
--------------------------------------------------------------------------    
 0 | 38  | 1985      | New York | Female | University | Dog     | Ping Pong
```

The problem I'm having is the list of attributes goes on and on and right now my user table has 20 something columns.

I feel I could normalize this by creating another table for each attribute see below. However this would create many joins and I'm still left with a lot of columns in the user table.

Solution #2 - `User` table:

```
id | age | birth day | City     | Gender | Education | fav Pet | fav hobbies
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 | 38  | 1985      | New York |   0    |      0    |     0   |     0
```

`Pets` table:

```
id | Pet Type
---------------
 0 | Dog
```

Anyone have any ideas how to approach this problem it feels like both answers are wrong. What is the proper table design for this database?

Comment: Look up "entity attribute value". Basically, some of your attributes don't "deserve" a column, they can just be a row in a table of key-value pairs.

Comment: But what about values from a drop down menu where the user can only input from a selected list lets say 4 choices for pets (dog,cat,bird,fish). Would that deserve a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more to this than meets the eye: First of all - if you have tons of attributes, many of which will likely be null for any specific row, and with a very dynamic selection of attributes (i.e. new attributes will appear quite frequently during the code's lifecycle), you might want to ask yourself, whether a RDBMS is the best way to materialize this ... essentially non-schema. Maybe a document store would be a better fit?

If you do want to stay in the RDBMS world, the canonical answer is to have either one or one-per-datatype property table plus a table of properties:

```
Users.id | .name | .birthdate | .Gender | .someotherfixedattribute
----------------------------------------------------------
1743     | Me.   | 01/01/1970 | M       | indeed


Propertytpes.id | .name
------------------------
  234           | pet 
  235           | hobby

Poperties.uid | .pid | .content
-----------------------------
1743          |  234 | Husky dog
```

Comment: I like your answer however most of the fields will be drop downs for example they wont type husky dog. They will have to select cat, dog or bird. In a way these feel fixed cause they can only pick from three choices. Would you then place the pets attribute in the usertable as a fixed field if they were limited to three choices?

Comment: Depends on the column count and if that attribute is likely to be fix or some sort of volatile

Comment: I have 10 to 15 columns that are drop down menus, and for each column the user can only input items i have put in the drop down menu. Would you consider a drop down menu to be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You have a comment and an answer that recommend (or at least suggest) and Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) model.

There is nothing wrong with using EAV if your attributes need to be dynamic, and your system needs to allow adding new attributes post-deployment.

That said, if your columns and relationships are all known up front, and they don't need to be dynamic, you are much better off creating an explicit model.  It will (generally) perform better and will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: Note that "easy to maintain" implies predicting what kinds of changes are most likely in the future: if the most likely change is more attributes being added, and the existing ones not changing, then an EAV structure will be much easier to maintain than a schema involving very wide tables or large numbers of very specific narrow tables.

Comment: Also, this should probably have been a comment in reply to my comment or the other answer, since it doesn't actually answer the original question.

Comment: Yes, the tables themselves may be easier to maintain in EAV. But there is more to maintaining a system than updating database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a wide table with a field per attribute, or many attribute tables, you could make a skinny table with many rows, something like:

```
Attributes (id,user_id,attribute_type,attribute_value)
```

Ultimately the best solution depends greatly on how the data will be used.  People can only have one DOB, but maybe you want to allow for multiple addresses (billing/mailing/etc.), so addresses might deserve a separate table.

Comment: Also the attributes which are not optional deserve a column